# Rails Multiple foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble combining multiple foreign keys on a has_many. I understand that this is not the express intent of the foreign_key on a has_many. But regardless I'm looking for a simple way to combine two foreign keys.

I've tried combining two has_many's like so:

```
has_many :primary_clients, foreign_key: :coach_id, inverse_of: :coach do
end

has_many :secondary_clients, foreign_key: :coach_two_id, inverse_of: :coach do
end

def clients
  Client.where("primary_clients = ? OR secondary_clients = ?", self.id, self.id)
end
```

And I've also tried unscope to redefine the scope:

```
has_many :clients, ->(user) { unscope(:where).where("coach_id = :id OR coach_two_id = :id", id: ids) }, inverse_of: :coach do
end
```

I'm after something like pretty simple like:

```
has_many :clients, foreign_key: {:coach_id, :coach_two_id}, inverse_of: :coach do
end
```

Any feedback to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

for a very small collection you could just do

`primary_clients | secondary_clients` with the `union` operator `|`